# Operador ternario y valor boleano

Tags: javascript, operador-ternario

les dejo el enunciado de un "problema" al que no logro encontrar la solución...

**Utilitzando el operador ternario y el valor booleano de 'sexoFemenino', si se cumple la condición, guarda en la variable 'genero' el valor string 'mujer', en caso contrario el valor será 'hombre'.**

He intentado investigar por mi cuenta pero no encuentro la información necesaria para hacer esto correctamente. Grácias

El código que estoy intentando sacar, y tengo hasta ahora es este:

```
sexoFemenino = (si) ? "mujer" : "hombre";
```

pero al ejecutarlo me dice esto :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: si is not defined at :1:1

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ¿Has olvidado definir la variable si? Pero en el enunciado no se menciona, te la has inventado. Te menciona la variable genero, a la que tienes que asignar valor según la variable sexoFemenino. Lee y entiende bien lo que se pide, es la primera condición para poder hacerlo bien.

Answer (score 1):

Es algo muy sencillo. El operador ternario es aquel que te permite trabajar con tres argumentos. La solución sería similar a:

```js
genero = sexoFemenino ? 'mujer' : 'hombre'
```

Te recomiendo empezar por: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que debes primero dar valor para comparar

```
var sexofemenino="si";
```

Luego comparas ese valor y lo asignas a otro

```
var genero=sexofemenino=="si"?"Mujer":"Hombre";
```

O lo Imprimes

```
console.log(sexofemenino=="si"?"Mujer":"Hombre");
```

Te dejo el Ejemplo Práctico

```js
var sexofemenino="si";

var genero=sexofemenino=="si"?"Mujer":"Hombre";

console.log(sexofemenino=="si"?"Mujer":"Hombre");

console.log(genero);
```

Answer (score 0):

El `si` que utilizas tiene que ser una variable que almacene un valor que imagino es ingresado por el usuario a través de un formulario o un cuadro emergente. De esa manera es que ese `si` pasa a formar parte de una condición a evaluar. Por ejemplo, si el usuario digita el valor `F`, entonces se imprime la palabra `Femenino`, caso contrario, `Masculino`, por lo que solo necesitarías colocar está condición: `si == 'F'`.